# If line has less than x words, then strip it

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text in `$text`:

```
$text = 'Hello world, lorem ipsum.

What?

Hello world, lorem ipsum what.

Excuse me!';
```

If the words on a line are less than 3 words, then I want to remove that line completely. So the lines with `What?` and `Excuse me!` should be removed from the string.

Is there a regex approach or how do I go about this?

Comment: I'm going to bounty this with 50 points once eligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this. Avoiding regex when possible is my preference, as regex tends to slow things down.

```
$str = 'Hello world, lorem ipsum.

What?

Hello world, lorem ipsum what.';

$new_str = explode("\n", $str);

foreach ($new_str as $keys => &$lines) {
    $lines = trim($lines);
    if (substr_count($lines, " ") < 2) {
         unset($new_str[$keys]);
    }
}

$new_str = implode("\n", $new_str);
print_r($new_str);
```

Which prints out this:

```
Hello world, lorem ipsum.
Hello world, lorem ipsum what.
```

Comment: Interesting approach. What's the quickest way to turn that array back into a string in the variable?

Comment: implode on the new lines. `$new_str = implode("\n", $new_str);`

Comment: Thanks, although I think this code counts double spaces as a word? A lot of the lines have a lot of empty space. This is an actual example string from our production site: http://pastebin.com/7Nb95EyN

Comment: This can be fixed by adding a `$lines = trim($lines)` in the foreach before the check for the substr_count of spaces.

Comment: For completion, can you please update your answer with the trim() approach and implode()

Comment: regex slow things down and & in foreach speed things up? I hardly doubt that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
preg_replace('/^(?!(?:\h*\S+\h+){2}\S+).*\R*/m', '', $text);
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world, lorem ipsum.
Hello world, lorem ipsum what.
```

`(?!(?:\S+\h+){3})` will match any line that doesn't have 3 non-space words. `\R` matches a newline character in PHP regex.

**Without lookahead** Use `preg_grep`:

```
echo implode("\n", preg_grep('/^\h*(?:\S+\h+){2}\S+/', explode("\n", $text)));
Hello world, lorem ipsum.
Hello world, lorem ipsum what.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG4kJ0/4)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/LQA7Ir)

Comment: I'm testing this but it doesn't seem to work properly. See my updated question with the variable. The "Excuse me!" line still remains in the string.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but by some reason, I cannot seem to make this work. I have an actual string that I'm testing it on, please test this $text string to confirm if it works for you: http://pastebin.com/7Nb95EyN

Comment: So the regex should remove the lines that say "advertisement" and so on. It echo's completely empty.

Comment: Yes I did, although please check the exactly string that I linked you with here: http://pastebin.com/7Nb95EyN

Comment: It does fail. Try `$text = 'one two three';`  and then an empty string is `echo`ed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression in `preg_replace`:

```
$test = preg_replace("/^(?!\h*\S+\h+\S+\h+\S+).*$\R?/m", "", $text);
```

Testing with input that touches on some additional boundary conditions:

```
$text = 'Hello world, lorem ipsum.
What? ending-spaces   
    Hello world, lorem
  Hello world, lorem ipsum what.
ending text';

$test = preg_replace("/^(?!\h*\S+\h+\S+\h+\S+).*$\R?/m", '', $text);

echo $test;
```

Output:

```
Hello world, lorem ipsum.
   Hello world, lorem
 Hello world, lorem ipsum what.
```

The `(?!` part looks ahead to see if -- after some optional horiontal blanks (`\h*`) -- there are three words (`\S+`) 
separated by (horizontal) blanks (`\h+`), and if so, does not match (so the line is not removed).
In all other cases the `.*$` will match anything until the end of the line, including the line-break (`\R`) if present (`?`) 
and will be replaced by an empty string, in order to remove that line.

The `m` modifier will make `^` and `$` match with the beginning and end of a line respectively
(instead of beginning and end of complete string).

Here is a [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/nN5yA7/1) using the above input and regex.